# how to make number repeatedly add in javascript

Tags: javascript

okay i guys i just got into java script and i made a simple game it works and does everything i wanted but now i want to make it difficult so that every time the enemy health is 0 it refill but comes back stronger as in it has more health this is what i came up with this is the part that makes it refill it adds 100 but only stays 200 when it refills i want it to increase by 100 every time it becomes 0

```
if (enemyHealth<=0) {
    enemyHealth=0;
    alert("you win");
    gold=gold+500;
    document.FGame.Output.value=gold;
    enemyHealth=100+100;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, it is not necessary to set enemyHealth to zero since you will be setting it later again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you always set the `enemyHealth` to 100 + 100, which will always equal 200. What you could do is to have a `totalEnemyHealth` variable which increase by 100 every time the enemy dies. When you revive that enemy, you would set it's health to the new `totalEnemyHealth` value.

```
//make sure not to re-initialize this variable every time
var totalEnemyHealth = 100;

//then in your function

 if (enemyHealth<=0){
    enemyHealth = totalEnemyHealth += 100;
    alert("you win")
    gold=gold+500;
    document.FGame.Output.value=gold;
}
```

However if you have multiple ennemies, that approach will not give the desired results. To solve your problem you will need something more object-oriented, such as all ennemies represented by an `Enemy` instance, where the instance would have the capability of tracking how many times it died and use this as a health multiplier.

Simple example:

```
var Enemy = {
    baseHealth: 100,
    health: 100,
    deathCount: 0,
    takeDamage: function (amount) {
       if ((this.health -= amount) <= 0) {
           this.die();
           this.respawn();
       }
    },
    die: function () {
        this.deathCount++;
    },
    respawn: function () {
        this.health = (this.deathCount + 1) * this.baseHealth;
    }
};

var someEnemy = Object.create(Enemy);

console.log(someEnemy.health); //100

someEnemy.takeDamage(150); //violent attack

console.log(someEnemy.health); //200
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a counter. Something simple like:

```
var counter=1; //at start of game
if (enemyHealth<=0)
{
    enemyHealth=0
    alert("you win")
    gold=gold+500;
    document.FGame.Output.value=gold;
    enemyHealth=100+(100*counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zhqg/1/

```
var gold = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var enemyHealth = num *i;
    if (enemyHealth<=0){
        //enemyHealth=0
        alert(i + "you win")
        gold+= 500;
       //document.FGame.Output.value=gold;
        enemyHealth += 100
        alert(enemyHealth);
    }
}
```

You can see when it runs, the number of times it hit 0 out of a for loop of 20 times. Then it bounces the health back to 100. I think this is what you need. - not 100% sure if I understand your use case.